# Putting coordinates of end point in shortest path algorithm

Tags: qgis, coordinates, qgis-modeler, shortest-path

How do I put the coordinates (x,y) of the end point of the shortest path algorithm (from vector to point) which is part of a QGIS model?

I'd like to get the calculated coordinates of a point (with the field calculator), that is an input of the model, and use this in the end point of the shortest path algorithm.

I want to avoid to put the coordinates as a string input of the model, but use the calculated coordinates of the point in input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression in the `End point` parameter in the `Shortest path` model algorithm:

```sql
attribute(get_feature_by_id('lyr_with_coords', 1), 'coordinates')
```

Where `lyr_with_coords` is the output of the `Field calculator` algorithm.

The expression gets the first (and only in my case) feature from the layer `lyr_with_coords`, and from that feature it gets the attribute value from the field `coordinates` (which is the result of an expression that generates the coordinates).

[image]

1. Name the output of the field calculator

[image]

2. In the `Shortest path` algorithm, change the input for `End point` from `Value` to `Pre-calculated Value` (which allows an expression)

[image]

3. Use the layer name and field name of the `Field calculator` output in the expression for the `End point` parameter

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply....but it doesn't work in my model. Honestly, i don't know why. The process is clear, are you sure that all is correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you get an error? The `End point` geometry must be very precise, it must be exactly on the network for a route to be calculated. If your calculated coordinates are not, you will have to add a step to find the nearest point on the network from your calculated point. To test I used vertex snapping with a new point layer and just calculated the `$x,$y` as a shortcut to get come coordinates.

Comment: No error, simply the paths are not created. I used vertex snapping and it's very precise. I tested this coordinates value also out of the model and the paths are ok. Is it ok that the "shortest path algorithm" is not connected to the "field calculator" block?

Comment: I added a step in my answer which might solve it. (Change the input type of the `End point` parameter from `Value` to `Pre-calculated Value`). Apologies, I missed that in my answer intially.

Comment: It's fine that they are not connected. If the Shortest path algorithm was using the output of the Field calculator directly they would be connected, but in this case the model makes a new layer from the field calculator (`lyr_with_coords`) and adds it to the canvas before picking it up again to use. I couldn't get `Shortest path` to recognise the output directly wthout making a new layer.

Comment: Ok, it's clear. It happens a strange thing, it works and create paths only when i run the model twice (with temporary output). Honestly, i don't know why.

Comment: I think that is because the model needs the calculated layer in the layer tree before the `Shortest path` algorithm can recognise it to get the coordinates with the expression. I have been trying to make the `Field calculator` a dependcy of the `Shortest path` algorithm but I cannot get it to work

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot solve it. Probably, i'm wrong in the setting of the dependencies or the expression in the coordinate calculated layer (field calculator). I tried many combinations.

Comment: I [posted a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/422167/128665) on this specific issue. Hopefully someone knows how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry again, i tried to export the model as a script python and i launched it (in qgis 3.16), but it shows an error saying "END_POINT parameter is not valid". The part of the script is like this:
# Shortest path (vector to point)
        alg_params = {
            'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,  
            'DEFAULT_SPEED': 10,
            'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
            'END_POINT': QgsExpression("attribute(get_feature_by_id('coord', 0), 'x_y')").evaluate(),
            'INPUT': outputs['graph']['OUTPUT'],
            'SPEED_FIELD': '',
            'START_POINTS': .....what could it be?