# QGIS Graphical Modeler - How to query features in algorithm output?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, qgis-modeler

I have a simple graphical model that uses a `Field calculator` to build a URL by concatenating strings in 3 fields of its input layer. This URL should be fed into the `Download File` algorithm using the `Pre-calculated Value` parameter.

For reproducibility, a valid download URL is:

> https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/geo-countries/countries/archive/23f420f929e0e09c39d916b8aaa166fb/countries.geojson

How do I use an expression in the `Download File` algorithm (`Pre-calculated Value`) to query the `Field Calculator` output?

Normally, on a map layer, to get the content of the `url` field of the feature with `id` = `1`, I would use:

```sql
attribute(get_feature_by_id('layer_name', 1), 'url')
```

In the expression builder there is a variable called `@Field_calculator_OUTPUT`, however substituting this for the layer name does not work:

```sql
attribute(get_feature_by_id( @Field_calculator_OUTPUT, 1), 'url')
```

[image]

The following error is thrown whereby there is no URL argument given:

```
Running Download file [3/3] Input Parameters: { DATA: '', METHOD: 0, OUTPUT: 'D:\\OneDrive\\geodata\\countries.geojson', URL: None } 
No URL specified Error encountered while running Download file Execution
failed after 0.18 seconds
```

I know that the URL is valid, I have tested it with the `Download File` tool outside the Graphical Modeller

I have tried using `'Calculated'` for the layer name in the expression and also using the `Rename Layer` algorithm and using the new layer name in the expression. I have also set the `Field Calculator` as a dependency of `Download File`.

I cannot get the expression to recognise the output of the `Field calculator` as a layer. The expression works if the layer is already present in the layer tree.

There is some degree of recognition of the layer because entering  `@Field_calculator_OUTPUT` in the expression makes a link between the two algorithms.

[image]

Comment: You cannot reference a temporary output within modeler, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397#issuecomment-505699624

Comment: I feared as much, thanks for investigating. Hopefully, given the recent discussion a fix will be applied soon.

Comment: @MrXsquared what about refering the initial (input) layer, thus not a temporary one, and concatenate the fields in the `Download file` dialog?

Comment: @Babel referencing a layer added to layerpanel works without issues.

Comment: Generally yes - but I didn't manage to concatenate three strings from three fields in a way as to work as input URL for the download file algorithm. Do you know how the syntax is? I guess this would also be a solution for OP - temporary output was from filed calculator that was only used to concatenate.

Comment: Using the field calculator and download file was more of a proof of concept for accessing a field calculator result, it was just an easy way to frame a question. I was attempting a slightly different use case but using the same principle. The important part was using an expression to reference a field calculation that was performed inside the model.

Comment: And what about saving the output of field calculator? Then it is not a temporary layer any more. If its true what @MrXsquared sayed, then the `Field Calculator` algorithm inseide the model builder would be completely useless - so there must be a way to access the result of it.

Comment: The entire output of the `Field Calculator` can be used as the input to a new algorithm. It just can't be filtered using an expression to get a single field value, unfortunately.

Comment: So can't you just save or rename the output of `Field Calculator`? Then you have a permanent layer to refer to...?

Comment: Not without breaking the model into two. The `Download File` algorithm will not pick it up until it is present in the layer tree. Which either means having separate models for the calculation and downloading the file, or running the model twice, the first time with an error, so that the `Download File` recognises the output as a map layer. Neither of which are particularly favourable. It should just be an intermediate step in the overall model. This is why I generally stick to scripts and not models.